# Can I store images on Database by using its reader.result from Javascript FileReader

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, database, file

I'm using this example https://jsfiddle.net/yv6vwr1z/2/

And I don't know if it's safe to store images on DataBase *(`Blob`)* by using its reader's result from Javascript *(`FileReader`)*

```
reader.onload = function (event) {  
    a.prop("href", event.target.result);
};
```